# Extracting data from very nested JSON in Azure SQL

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-blob-storage

I have nested JSON file:

```
"vehicleStatusResponse": {
    "vehicleStatuses": [
        {
            "vin": "ABC1234567890",
            "triggerType": {
                "triggerType": "TIMER",
                "context": "RFMS",
                "driverId": {
                    "tachoDriverIdentification": {
                        "driverIdentification": "123456789",
                        "cardIssuingMemberState": "BRA",
                        "driverAuthenticationEquipment": "CARD",
                        "cardReplacementIndex": "0",
                        "cardRenewalIndex": "1"
                    }
                }
            },
            "receivedDateTime": "2020-02-12T04:11:19.221Z",
            "hrTotalVehicleDistance": 103306960,
            "totalEngineHours": 3966.6216666666664,
            "driver1Id": {
                "tachoDriverIdentification": {
                    "driverIdentification": "BRA1234567"
                }
            },
            "engineTotalFuelUsed": 48477520,
            "accumulatedData": {
                "durationWheelbaseSpeedOverZero": 8309713,
                "distanceCruiseControlActive": 8612200,
                "durationCruiseControlActive": 366083,
                "fuelConsumptionDuringCruiseActive": 3064170,
                "durationWheelbaseSpeedZero": 5425783,
                "fuelWheelbaseSpeedZero": 3332540,
                "fuelWheelbaseSpeedOverZero": 44709670,
                "ptoActiveClass": [
                    {
                        "label": "wheelbased speed >0",
                        "seconds": 16610,
                        "meters": 29050,
                        "milliLitres": 26310
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "wheelbased speed =0",
                        "seconds": 457344,
                        "milliLitres": 363350
```

It is already imported from Azure BLOB Storage to SQL DB and now I need to extract data from it to table. I've already used a T-SQL request to do that, but it returned me blank table with only headers:

```
SELECT response.*
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'response3.json', DATA_SOURCE = 'VCBI24', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
    WITH ( vehiclestatusResponse nvarchar (100), vehicleStatuses nvarchar (100), vin nvarchar (100), triggerType nvarchar (100), context nvarchar (100) and etc...) AS response
```

How can I handle it?

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: Hi @hatorihanso - any update on this?  Please upvote and / or mark as answered if this has been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a path with `OPENJSON` which allows you to drill in to nested JSON, eg

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.vehicleStatusResponse.vehicleStatuses' )
WITH (
    vin VARCHAR(50)  '$.vin',
    triggerType VARCHAR(50)  '$.triggerType.triggerType',
    context VARCHAR(50)  '$.triggerType.context',
    driverIdentification VARCHAR(50)     '$.triggerType.driverId.tachoDriverIdentification.driverIdentification',
    cardIssuingMemberState VARCHAR(50)   '$.triggerType.driverId.tachoDriverIdentification.cardIssuingMemberState',

    receivedDateTime DATETIME    '$.receivedDateTime',

    engineTotalFuelUsed INT  '$.engineTotalFuelUsed'

    )
```

Full script example:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"vehicleStatusResponse": {
  "vehicleStatuses": [
    {
      "vin": "ABC1234567890",
      "triggerType": {
        "triggerType": "TIMER",
        "context": "RFMS",
        "driverId": {
          "tachoDriverIdentification": {
            "driverIdentification": "123456789",
            "cardIssuingMemberState": "BRA",
            "driverAuthenticationEquipment": "CARD",
            "cardReplacementIndex": "0",
            "cardRenewalIndex": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      "receivedDateTime": "2020-02-12T04:11:19.221Z",
      "hrTotalVehicleDistance": 103306960,
      "totalEngineHours": 3966.6216666666664,
      "driver1Id": {
        "tachoDriverIdentification": {
          "driverIdentification": "BRA1234567"
        }
      },
      "engineTotalFuelUsed": 48477520,
      "accumulatedData": {
        "durationWheelbaseSpeedOverZero": 8309713,
        "distanceCruiseControlActive": 8612200,
        "durationCruiseControlActive": 366083,
        "fuelConsumptionDuringCruiseActive": 3064170,
        "durationWheelbaseSpeedZero": 5425783,
        "fuelWheelbaseSpeedZero": 3332540,
        "fuelWheelbaseSpeedOverZero": 44709670,
        "ptoActiveClass": [
          {
            "label": "wheelbased speed >0",
            "seconds": 16610,
            "meters": 29050,
            "milliLitres": 26310
          },
          {
            "label": "wheelbased speed =0",
            "seconds": 457344,
            "milliLitres": 363350
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}}}}}}}}'


SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.vehicleStatusResponse.vehicleStatuses' )
WITH (
    vin VARCHAR(50)  '$.vin',
    triggerType VARCHAR(50)  '$.triggerType.triggerType',
    context VARCHAR(50)  '$.triggerType.context',
    driverIdentification VARCHAR(50)     '$.triggerType.driverId.tachoDriverIdentification.driverIdentification',
    cardIssuingMemberState VARCHAR(50)   '$.triggerType.driverId.tachoDriverIdentification.cardIssuingMemberState',

    receivedDateTime DATETIME    '$.receivedDateTime',

    engineTotalFuelUsed INT  '$.engineTotalFuelUsed'


    )
```

My results:

[image: Results]

Read more about `OPENJSON` here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

A second example.  With OPENJSON you can either supply the json path expression is more explicit and gives you more control particularly for nested JSON.  If the JSON is relatively simple, you do not have to supply the paths, eg

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = '{
  "ptoActiveClass": [
    {
      "label": "wheelbased speed >0",
      "seconds": 16610,
      "meters": 29050,
      "milliLitres": 26310
    },
    {
      "label": "wheelbased speed =0",
      "seconds": 457344,
      "milliLitres": 363350
    }
  ]
}'


SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.ptoActiveClass' )
WITH (
    label VARCHAR(50),
    seconds INT,
    meters INT,
    milliLitres INT
    )

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.ptoActiveClass' )
WITH (
    label VARCHAR(50)    '$.label',
    seconds VARCHAR(50)  '$.seconds',
    meters VARCHAR(50)   '$.meters',
    milliLitres VARCHAR(50)  '$.milliLitres'
    )
```

Comment: Hi @wBob ! Thanks for you answer, but I need to extract data from json file, which is already located in BLOB-storage. No need to declare it separately...Trying to adopt your script.

Comment: Yes, that just for the example, to show the technique.  I like all my scripts to run end-to-end and obviously I don't have access to your blob store!  : )

Comment: Hi @wBob ! Please could you explain how to extract strings below? Can't find any info in MicrosoftDocs link:  "ptoActiveClass": [
          {
            "label": "wheelbased speed >0",
            "seconds": 16610,
            "meters": 29050,
            "milliLitres": 26310
          },
          {
            "label": "wheelbased speed =0",
            "seconds": 457344,
            "milliLitres": 363350
          }
        ]

Comment: I will add another example to cover this.  Can I first check that you know how to upvote questions if they are helpful and that you know how to [mark them as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: it would be awesome, if you can explain ;) yes, I know how to do it.

Comment: big thanks! Do you have any idea how is it possible to combine two your example in one script? It will be very helpful because I need to extract this JSON using one script in Azure to make ETL for data analysis.

Comment: Hi, yes use the path technique from the first answer.

Comment: In this case I have some troubles, when use 1st example for extracting arrays like “ptoActiveClass” - the result is  a blank row.